# How can i set different names to DataTemplate elements?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i'm making something like TicTacToeGame, trying to use MVVM and at this point i faced a problem. I can't understand how can i (if it's even possible), set different names to different DataTempalte elements("Buttons" to be exact).

```
<Window x:Class="TicTacToeCommand.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TicTacToeCommand"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="400"
    Background="White"
    Name="mainW">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonsStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ElementName=mainW, Path=DataContext.GetButtonPressCommand}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="47*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonsList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Content}"
                        Name="b1"
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonsStyle}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=b1, Path=Name}">
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" Name="uniformGrid1">
                </UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

That's my XAML code.
And also, i'm trying to send the name as a Command Parameter in a Command, but im allways getting "b1" name, because they all getting it and i need them all to have different name...

If it is possible how after this I send these names to command?

I will be very grateful for the help, and please excuse me in advance for possible mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

element name, especially in template, doesn't help a lot

```
<Button Content="{Binding Content}"
        Name="b1"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonsStyle}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=b1, Path=Name}">
```

button is bound to some item here. why not send that item as CommandParameter?

```
<Button Content="{Binding Content}"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonsStyle}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}">
```

then in view model you can cast to item type and get acces to all its properties (`Content`, etc)

Comment: Yes, I can do so but Is this not a violation of MVVM, to send button to viewmodel?

Comment: But still is there a way to give different names to my element(b1,b2,b3...)?

Comment: @kotki, you are using `ButtonsList` in view model. CommandParameter would be a single element of that list. if first part is acceptable for you, the second is the same. regarding names: i didn't try to do that, simple attemp says that Name doesn't support MarkupExtension like Binding

Comment: my button list is not actually System.Windows.Controls.Button List, i just created my own class and named it Button, and my list contains those buttons!